# dyn:evaluate() inside <xsl:for-each> yields strange results

Tags: xslt, xalan

Consider the following XSL transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
           xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
           extension-element-prefixes="dyn">
    <xsl:variable name="_raw">
        <test>1</test>
        <test>2</test>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="list" select="exsl:node-set($_raw)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:for-each select="$list/test">
                <loop>
                    <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate('exsl:node-set($list)/test')"/>
                </loop>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Executing this on any input gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
    <loop>1</loop>
    <loop/>
</result>
```

What I don't understand is:

- The `esxl:note-set()` inside `dyn:evaluate()` is necessary if I want to reference `$list` in the XPath string. Otherwise, the first `<loop>` is also empty. Why? `$list` is already a node set.
- It's exactly the same code executed twice. Why does it yield no result the second time?
- This works if I don't take the values from `$list`, but from the XML input instead. Where's the difference?
- If I remove the `<xsl:for-each>`, `dyn:evaluate()` works without the `exsl:node-set()` in it. Why? There's no reference to the context in the expression that is evaluated, it shouldn't make a difference.

My XSLT processor is Xalan 2.7.2.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I may have, but sadly I don't remember and cannot look for it since the code belongs to a company I don't work for anymore. I do remember that the answer here did not solve my problem and I probably restructured my code to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
           xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
           extension-element-prefixes="exsl dyn">
    <xsl:variable name="_raw">
        <test>1</test>
        <test>2</test>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="list" select="exsl:node-set($_raw)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:for-each select="$list/test">
                <loop>
                    <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate(.)"/>
                </loop>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Which will result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result><loop>1</loop><loop>2</loop></result>
```

---

### Edit:

I am still not sure what you are after here, but let me point out a few details:

> It's exactly the same code executed twice. Why does it yield no result
>   the second time?

That may be a bug in Xalan. If you run your code with libxslt, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<result xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"><loop>1</loop><loop>1</loop></result>
```

> The esxl:note-set() inside dyn:evaluate() is necessary if I want to
>   reference $list in the XPath string. Otherwise, the first  is
>   also empty. Why? $list is already a node set.

I don't think it's necessary. Or perhaps I don't understand what it's necessary **for**. In any case, changing this:

```
<loop>
    <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate('exsl:node-set($list)/test')"/>
</loop>
```

to:

```
<loop>
    <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate('$list/test')"/>
</loop>
```

will result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"><loop>1</loop><loop>1</loop></result>
```

and this time the result is same for both Xalan and libxslt.

Comment: That was not the question, I wouldn't need `dyn:evaluate` at all here. My code is just a minimal working example for showing the problems I have. The actual code needs the reference to `$list` in the evaluated XPath string because that string is used as parameter value for another template and is evaluated there, in a completely different context.

Comment: @flyx I am afraid your question is not clear then. You started by the premise that the "*esxl:note-set() inside dyn:evaluate() is necessary*". That is not true, and that's what my answer is designed to show.

Comment: @flyx I have added a few pointers to my answer. If that's still not what you're looking for, I suggest you get **much** more specific, i.e post the expected result vs. actual result for each case you wish to examine - and make sure to provide the **complete** code necessary to reproduce the issue (or rather issues).